# unable to build nw.js with diskdb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, require, nw.js

I am developing a sample desktop application using node webkit and angular js referring [this tutorial](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/) series. I had used the diskdb for storing the data and will be connected as,

```
var db = require('diskdb');
 db.connect('appDB', ['users']);

    // get the user list
 var users = db.users.find();
```

And when running the application using the command `sudo nwbuild -v 0.12.3 -r /home/path/to/myapp/folder/` it works fine as desired and populate the list of users in frontend.

But when I build the application as package using `sudo nwbuild -p linux -v 0.12.3 -o ~/Documents/output/ /home/path/to/myapp/folder/` and when i run the built application, it gives the following error.

```
code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
message: "Cannot find module 'diskdb'"
```

How can I fix the same?

Comment: how to avoid Unexpected end of input error which comes very first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by copying the `nod_modules` folder wich contains the diskdb dependency files to root folder of the project and by using relative path to the diskdb folder in the connection string as,

```
var db = require('./node_modules/diskdb');
  db.connect('appDB', ['users']);
```